# How to publish google apps script website

Tags: google-apps-script, google-play-developer-api

I wrote a simple Google Apps Script to launch google website. Its integrated with google sheet to get data from it. If I press publish button on the menu it works well. However, I pasted the url into another browser which has not same session with google apps script editor it is not working while attempts login to google.

The google account is not for google play developer. Should I register my google account as google play developer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your Web App "Who has access to the app:" property to "Anyone, even anonymous".